# Receiving a full string via serial

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a new program to communicate via serial rs232 to a device that uses a proprietary communication protocol.

i'm using the SerialPort1_DataReceived handler,but it doesn't seem to work.

these are the settings of the serial port:

```
 SerialPort1.PortName = ComboBox1.Text
 SerialPort1.BaudRate = ComboBox2.Text
 SerialPort1.Parity = Parity.None
 SerialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One
 SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
 SerialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")
 SerialPort1.ReadTimeout = 1
 SerialPort1.WriteTimeout = 500
 SerialPort1.DtrEnable = Enabled
```

i tried this method too:

```
 Dim buffRecei As Byte() = New Byte(SerialPort1.BytesToRead) {}  
 SerialPort1.Read(buffRecei, 0, buffRecei.Length) 
 stringInput = BitConverter.ToString(buffRecei)
```

but it doesnt work too

right now while it receives the data i use the & to append it to a string, but i want a solution that gives me the full string once is all received in the buffer.

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived

   Dim numBytes As Integer = SerialPort1.BytesToRead
   Dim buffer(numBytes - 1) As Byte
   SerialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, numBytes)
   stringInput &= (BitConverter.ToString(buffer))
   ReceivedText(stringInput.Replace("-", ""))
End Sub
```

i also used the `stringInput.Replace("-", ""))` because sometimes in the string there are - and i dont know why

the input from the serial is something like this "346586A9B2C0"
i expect to get the full string once the sting is fully recieved and not piece by piece

this is the part where the string gets displayed in a textbox

```
Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String) 'input from ReadExisting 

    If Me.RichTextBox2.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
        Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
    Else
        Me.RichTextBox2.Text = [text]
    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: How will vb.net "know" when the full string is received? Having to concatenate the incoming data is not uncommon in a lot of environments and languages, not just vb.

Comment: 1 ms timeout on receive seems very short, depending on the baudrate. BTW you didn't specify the baudrate in the settings.

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli 
the baudrate is set via a combobox same as the portname. the baudrate set will be 9600.
is there a way to use the timeout on receive to know when the string is fully recieved?

Comment: The bit time at 9600 is 1/9600s, that is 1/10th of a millisecond. One byte is 10 times longer, that is 1 ms. Your timeout is of the same size of the byte time, which is incorrect. There is no way to know when the string is fully received unless you know either the protocol or at least the break time of the transmitting device. If you don't know any of these, you have to do some trial and error, by starting at 100ms and reducing the read timeout progressively until you get the expected result. But since you are using DTR, maybe the terminal is piloting the line to signal when is transmitting...

Comment: form the protocol document it says the end of the communication from the slave so the last byte of the string is 11xx.xxx (the x can be either 1 or 0) so how should i do to check if every byte contains 1100.0000?

Comment: By doing exactly what you don't like to do, reading only a single byte at a time.  You need a field in your class that stores those bytes, like the *buffer* you now have declared as a local variable.  Another one that keeps track of the number of bytes in the buffer.  Just make the array big enough.so it can store any response.

Comment: @HansPassant can you please show below your version? thx !

Comment: Bitshifting 6 bits rightwise and comparing, that would be: If byte >> 6 = &B11 Then 'stop receiving which is the same as base-10:  If byte >> 6 = 3 Then 'stop receiving but as said above it would require you read one byte at a time. It is also possible to do bitwise comparison: if byte And &B11000000 = &B11000000 Then 'stop receiving